# how to verify the condition using verifytext and store the value in to variable either true or false

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a application which contains 3 pages.

The navigation of the flow is 
If it is a first login: Page A --> Page B --> Page C

For subsequent login: Page A --> Page C

Here my condition is I will check some of the text in Page B using verifyTextPresent. If yes, I will do some operation to go to Page C and then i will do my activities in Page C. If no, I will do the activity directly in Page C.

I need to verify the text by VerifyTextPresent and if exists i set a value true to any variable and then the second step i will variable is true or false and then i will proceed.

How to attain this? also if you have any other idea also would be fine for me...

Thanks in advance..
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

|open|http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/flowControl||

|gotoIfAndWait|selenium.isTextPresent("flowControl")|YesIsPresent|

|gotolabel|NoNotPresent||

|label|YesIsPresent||

|verifyTextPresent|"I'm in Page B"||

|clickAndWait|'SubmitTheFormToGoToPageC'||

|label|NoNotPresent||

|verifyTextPresent|"I'm in Page C"||

|clickAndWait|xpath=html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a[1]||